# Что означает for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)

Tags: javascript

Типа нарастающая (+1)? Можете показать примеры кода побольше?

Comment: Пардон, но почему бы не почитать об основах языка?

Answer (score 5):

Выражение `for` создаёт цикл, состоящий из 3 необязательных выражений в круглых скобках, разделённых точками с запятой.

Синтаксис

```
for ([инициализация]; [условие]; [финальное выражение]) выражение
```

`финальное выражение` - Выражение, выполняющееся в конце интерации цикла. Там можно записать что угодно, но чаще всего пишут увеличение счётчика.

`условие` - Выражение, выполняющееся на каждой интерации цикла. Если выражение истинно, цикл выполняется.

`++` - Унарный оператор. Добавляет единицу к своему операнду. Если используется в качестве префикса (++x), то возвращает значение операнда с добавленной к нему единицей; а в случае применения в качестве окончания (x++) возвращает значение операнда перед добавлением к нему единицы.

---

По сути, в данном случае `i++` это `i = i + 1`

А цикл будет выполняться до тех пор, пока выполняется `[условие]`, т.е. в текущем случае пока значение `i` меньше длины массива `lines`

Comment: То есть по сути это просто обычный цикл. Если в него поместить условие, то при выполнении этого условия к i будет прибавляться +1 и так до бесконечности?

Comment: Вопрос плохой, а ответ - отличный! +1 от меня.

Comment: @ИванИванов до тех пор, пока выполняется `[условие]`, т.е. пока значение i меньше длины массива lines

Comment: Алексей, добавьте ему ещё расшифровку, что делает `let` - а ну как не поймёт...

Comment: Только инициализация - не выражение, а statement.

Comment: @Qwertiy прошу прощения, я не понял)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну выражение - это обычно expression, у которого есть значение. `let x` - не expression. Хотя, если подумать, то я тоже неправ и запихнуть какой-нибудь произвольный statement, например, `if(1)0` туда нельзя.

Comment: @ИванИванов Если ответ помог - галочка слева от ответа - тык)